# Counting all matrices in a family obeying a certain rule

Tags: matrix, counting

I would like to use the `Count[list, pattern]` method to count all 4x4 matrices with entries in $\lbrace 0 ,1 \rbrace$ that have a certain Jordan canonical form. The problem is that I haven't the slightest clue how to "generate" the family of matrices or phrase the rule in the argument of `Count`... how would I go about these things? Any help is much appreciated (and sorry if this is a basic question that could've been found with more persistent google-ing).

Comment: It's very hard to give advice as to how to generate the family of matrices without any details about this family.

Comment: @yohbs The only rules I have for this family are that all matrices should be 4x4 and the entries should be either 0 or 1. From there, I want to count all of the matrices in this family that have a certain Jordan form (pattern argument).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fourbyfourbinarymatrices = Tuples[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];

Length @ fourbyfourbinarymatrices
```

> 65536

Among the first 1000 elements of `fourbyfourbinarymatrices` 136 of them have a `JordanDecomposition` whose first component has a trace equal to 2:

```
Count[fourbyfourbinarymatrices[[;; 1000]],
   _?(Tr[JordanDecomposition[#][[1]]] == 2 &)]
```

> 136

And 4 of them have a similarity matrix in their `JordanDecomposition` that is equal to `Reverse/@IdentityMatrix[4]`:

```
Count[fourbyfourbinarymatrices[[;; 1000]], 
  _?(JordanDecomposition[#][[1]] === (Reverse /@ IdentityMatrix[4]) &)]
```

> 4

Comment: The concrete constructions and examples are very helpful. Thanks a bunch! Follow-up question: how does Mathematica enumerate the tuples in our matrix list?

Comment: @Dan, glad it was useful. Thank you for the accept. Welcome mma.se. Re how `Tuples` enumerates the tuples, I don't know how it is implemented.

Comment: @Dan This should give you some hint: `base = 2;
FromDigits[Flatten[#], base] & /@ Tuples[Range[0, base-1], {4, 4}][[1 ;; 10]]` ;o) Does also work with other bases...

Answer (score 1):

```
Count[myMatrixList, # == JordanDecomposition[#]&]
```